# if admob ads dont show game freezes in unity android app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I have this Unity game for android and i'm trying to use the `admob plugin`. 
I request a banner 5 seconds after starting game and every 45 seconds after that. Sometimes banner doesn't show up i have no idea why. The real problem is if banner doesn't show and i try to quit the game by calling:

```
Application.Quit()
```

or

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

it freezes and doesn't quit so i quit with home button. Next time i try to run the game it doesn't start if i don't force close it before running. Any ideas why i can't quit properly or the banner not showing?

EDIT: I've put the game on play store and asked a friend to test it. Ads show every time he runs the game

Comment: I'm not familiar with Unity, but the admob SDK usually writes a lot of logs (in the LogCat at least), have you tried looking into them to determine what is wrong?

Comment: Did you run admob in async?

Comment: sorry don't know what you mean by async

Comment: Look here if it helps ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41531875/interestial-ads-not-showing-on-live-android-device-for-game-build-in-unity-4-6?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but I cannot comment yet. I currently had the same problem .. after hours of searching the problem disappeared from alone. I got the same freeze when no banner was retrieved (there was no "success" in logcat.

Looked like every second start I failed to get an ad. If I turn off internet, the game works normal. So there may be something wrong with the AdFailed-Handling .. I havent found out what it was, because it works without any problem in regular java projects, but fails in unity projects (having the same API JAR used). No matter if real or test ads.

So maybe give it 24 hours if you've just created a new ad-id

I still would be highly interested if this can be fixed in a proper way or if it is an error in the latest unity update (which happened yesterday)

Comment: Theres also another game i play wich has the same issue. Only diference is that game quits but doesn't start the next time u try to.